# init YADCF inside datatable draw event

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatable, twig, yadcf

I'm using `stwe`'s datatable bundle and rendering the datatable using twig. I need to insert some chosen filters in my table's head, but the following code doesn't return the table.

```
var oTable;
oTable = $('#content_datatable').DataTable();
oTable.on('draw.dt', function () {
    yadcf.init(oTable[{
        column_number: 0
    },
    {
        column_number: 1,
        filter_type: "multi_select",
        select_type: 'chosen'
    }]);
});
```

removing `$('#content_datatable').DataTable()` returns my table, but without any filter. How can I add the filters? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
var oTable;
oTable = $('#content_datatable').DataTable();
yadcf.init(oTable[{
    column_number: 0
},
{
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: "multi_select",
    select_type: 'chosen'
}]);
```

yadcf will bind itself to the event of datatbles.

If the above code wont work please provide error from console / link to a test case

p.s

You must include chosen js/css files in your web page

Comment: sorry about the delay. No,it doesn't work, and there's no error in console. as I said, the symfony bundle is already initializing the table, so adding the initialization code again is probably what's wrong.

Comment: then you should see where the `$('#content_datatable').DataTable();` is being called in symfony and look for a way to add the `yadcf.init` right after that... you can ask on the relevant github project repository...

Comment: I will try that. sorry for the late reply, I have been taking care of a million things. :)